# CSS lint throwing error

Tags: css, csslint

[csslint.net](http://csslint.net/) is throwing errors for the following css and I don't know why. This is pretty normal for css I think. I got the css from this [site](http://codepen.io/ace-subido/pen/Cuiep).

```
body {
    background: #eee !important;    
}

.wrapper {  
    margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.form-signin {
  max-width: 380px;
  padding: 15px 35px 45px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);  

  .form-signin-heading,
    .checkbox {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .form-control {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 16px;
      height: auto;
      padding: 10px;
        @include box-sizing(border-box);

        &:focus {
          z-index: 2;
        }
    }

    input[type="text"] {
      margin-bottom: -1px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }

    input[type="password"] {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
      border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me? I really don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: What errors is it throwing? Can you include error messages in your question? Also, is the CSS code site you're linking to relevant to your question? It could be seen as a solicitation (contrasting opinions invited).

Comment: Are you aware of the box-sizing mixin that is being included? Is your lint progam cool with those?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty malformed, run that into any editor with color syntax highlighting and you'll see that there are missing closing parenthesis for a few rules or they are incorrectly nested - you can't nest normal rules in CSS (media queries are an exception).

You'll need to look over your code and make sure you're not trying to nest rules.

Comment: Oh yeah it's the nesting that is the problem. This must be scss??